# By code that lets the second video start after the first finish ? Or i must use scripts for this to work?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

I have 2 links for videos coded in `<div>`. I need a help by code to let the second video play automatically after the first video has ended.

I am using CSS and HTML5.

This is the code:

```
<div class="container2">
  <video controls src="System Software & Application Software.mp4" autoplay></video>
</div>
<div class="container3">
  <video controls src="What is Computer Hardware.mp4"autoplay> </video>
</div>
```

Comment: code written in <div>

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: <div class="container2"><video controls src="System Software & Application Software.mp4"autoplay>
</video></div>
<div class="container3"><video controls src="What is Computer Hardware.mp4"autoplay>
</video></div> @Pete

Comment: Edit the question, don't put it in the comments

Comment: Your second `autoplay` attribute does not have any separating whitespace before it, and so browsers may struggle to interpret it correctly.

Comment: Please take a moment to learn how to format block and inline code here. You can do so by searching the phrase "how to format code on Stack Overflow" in a search engine. Please do not make posts saying that you could not format it because you don't know how to - that just creates work for other people.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help .I'll learn how to format a code in stack Overflow. Thank you one more time @ halfer

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the autoplay from the second video, then create an eventListener on your first video to listen for the `ended` event and then trigger the second video to play. For instance, with this HTML:

```
<div class="container2">
    <video id="video1" controls src="System Software & Application Software.mp4" autoplay> </video>
</div> 
<div class="container3">
    <video id="video2" controls src="What is Computer Hardware.mp4"> </video>
</div>
```

Your JavaScript could look something like this:

```
document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('ended',function() {
    document.getElementById('video2').play();
},false);
```